# Integral $6\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x}^{y=1}\int_{z=x}^{z=y} f(x) f(y) f(z)dxdydz=\bigg(\int_0^1 f(t) dt\bigg)^3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

Prove that
$$
6\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\int_{y=x}^{y=1}\int_{z=x}^{z=y} f(x) f(y) f(z)dxdydz=\bigg(\int_0^1 f(t) dt\bigg)^3
$$
assuming $f(x)$ is continuous on [0,1].  This is from an old Putnam exam.  I am not really sure how to start the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are integrating over the part $0 \leqslant x \leqslant z \leqslant y \leqslant 1$ of the unit cube. The integrand is invariant under permutations of the coordinates, and the six permutations of $x,y,z$ cover the entire unit cube, so

$$6\int_{x=0}^{x=1} \int_{y=x}^{y=1}\int_{z=x}^{z=y}f(x)f(y)f(z)\,dz\,dy\,dx = \int_0^1\int_0^1\int_0^1 f(x)f(y)f(z)\,dz\,dy\,dx.$$

The last integral is easily recognised as

$$\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right)^3$$

since the integrand is a product of functions of one variable.

Comment: Very Clear. Thanks